# Error in SQL Select Where statement

Tags: php, sql, syntax, where-clause

Got myself the following error and I can't seem to figure out why:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near **'s-Gravenmoer''** at line 1

This is the SQL syntax:

```
$plaats = $row['plaats'];    

$query10 = "SELECT * FROM gebieden WHERE plaats = '$plaats'";
```

For those interested, the variable has this content: 's-Gravenmoer

Why is it giving me an error?
Thanks!

Comment: this kind of db operaction is disaster... var_dump($query10); output is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysql_real_escape_string` or `htmlspecialchars`

```
$plaats = $row['plaats'];    

$query10 = "SELECT * FROM gebieden WHERE plaats = '".mysql_real_escape_string($plaats)."';";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the value of `$plaats` contains single quote.

You're code is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM gebieden WHERE plaats = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $plaats);
    if ($stmt->execute()) 
    {
      while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
      {
        print_r($row);
      }
    }
?>
```

this will allow you to search records with single quotes.

Comment: Well, my code isn't at risk for SQL injection, because the user can only input something in this table with a selection box, they cannot enter a string or anything... That said, thanks for you code, gonna test it right away!

Comment: @user1555076 if that's the case use alternative `mysql_real_escape_string($plaats)`

Comment: @user1555076 if you do that, then it's fine.